# C#: Windows 10 Universal App EXPORT as library

Tags: c#, win-universal-app

I want to export my project as a library to not copy the classes manually into future projects.

Does anyone know how to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have class library projects in your project, then you will have dll file per each, meaning that you can just add reference to those dll files in each solution that you want.

However, that is only a good idea if you don't need to change the code inside your future ones.

You can also take a look at creating nuget packages, if you want to configure some stuff.

Comment: The code will not have to be changed. I am going to try this out. Thank you!